# error 404 for REST web service

Tags: web-services, rest

I have deployed a REST service in a local SharePoint 2013 with Visual Studio 2012.

Anyway, when I try to access the svc url:

```
http://mylocalpc/_vti_bin/adsvc/Service.svc
```

I get error **404** file not found.

I have followed this [tutorial](http://jbarkes.blogspot.it/2014/04/sharepoint-2013-create-custom-wcf-rest.html)

so in my solution there is an isapi folder which contains an adsvc folder. In this folder there are the following files:

**Service.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
    Service="adservice.Service, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
    CodeBehind="Service.svc.cs"
    Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory,
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=40e75731a61cae52" %>
```

**Service.svc.cs**

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace adservice
{

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]

// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
// NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
public class Service : IService
{
    public Service() { }

    public string HelloWorld()
    {

        return "test";
    }
}

}
```

**IService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace adservice
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "HelloWorld")]
        string HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

What could be wrong?

**EDIT:**
I see this in the ULS log:

> Application error when access /_vti_bin/adsvc/Service.svc, Error=Could
>   not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime,
>   Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40e75731a61cae52' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)      at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName)      at System.Type.GetType(String typeName,
>   Boolean throwOnError)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceParser.GetType(String typeName) 
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceParser.CreateParseString(Assembly
>   compiledAssembly)      at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.CreateBuildResult(CompilerResults
>   results)      at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetBuildResult(CompilerResults
>   results)      at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath)      at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate)      at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)      at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate)      at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledCustomString(String
>   virtualPath)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.GetCompiledCustomString(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo
>   serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)

Comment: I used ASP.NET web service and got this done without any error.

Comment: @Malin De Silva Have tried this with SharePoint?

Comment: Yes created the service and connected that with a service reference.